# CSS only language dropdown won't collapse on iOS safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, drop-down-menu

**Problem 1**

When opening on an iOS device in the default browser Safari, the following language picker dropdown menu cannot be opened other than by tapping on the flag. On the other hand on Android, the entire area is tapable and will open the dropdown as expected.

**Problem 2**

On iOS the dropdown cannot be closed / collapsed by tapping outside of the dropdown. On Android, on the other hand, it works fine.

The code seperated in HTML and CSS:
https://jsfiddle.net/DanielFiddler/whd15fb4/9/

Open this in your mobile browser to show only the result and experience the behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/DanielFiddler/whd15fb4/9/show

The dropdown is completely made with CSS, without JS. I would prefer to keep it JS-free. (Though if the fix is not at all achievable only with CSS, then I would also be fine with JS).

The dropdown is based on the following reference. I am wondering why the reference works fine on iOS though:
https://codepen.io/axel1998/pen/RWOpXq

Only result for mobile view:
https://codepen.io/axel1998/full/RWOpXq

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>dropdown lang fail</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<style>

body {
    background: url('https://i.imgur.com/OHWet61.jpg');
    background-color: #40403d;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: #565656;
}

.lang-element {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 4px 0px;
}

.lang-element:hover {
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.lang-element-selected {
    background-color: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    display: none !important;
}

.lang-name {
    font-size: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: -2px;
}

.img-lang {
    width: 26px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 3px;
}

.lang-active {
    display: block;
}

.lang-dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    color: #999;
}

.languagepicker {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    margin: 8px 2px 10px 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 4px;
    z-index: 9999;
    border: none;
    font-size: 85%;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

.languagepicker:hover {
    /* don't forget the 1px border */
    height: 128px;
}

.languagepicker a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.languagepicker li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.languagepicker li:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}

.languagepicker a:first-child li {
    border: none;
    background: #000 !important;
}

.languagepicker li img {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#lang-headline {
    display: none;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<ul class="languagepicker">

    <li id="lang-headline">Language</li>

    <li class="lang-active">
        <img class="img-lang" src="https://i.imgur.com/rtm50Az.png" alt="">
        <div class="lang-name">English</div>
        <div class="lang-dropdown">&#9660;</div>
    </li>

    <!--EN-->
    <li class="lang-element lang-element-selected">
            <img class="img-lang" src="https://i.imgur.com/rtm50Az.png" alt="">
            <div class="lang-name">English</div>
    </li>

    <!--DE-->
    <li class="lang-element">
        <a href="https://www.example.de">
            <img class="img-lang" src="https://i.imgur.com/glsOlnC.png" alt="">
            <div class="lang-name">Deutsch</div>
        </a>
    </li>

    <!--FR-->   
    <li class="lang-element">
        <a href="https://www.example.com/fr/">
            <img class="img-lang" src="https://i.imgur.com/84dfcDi.png" alt="">
            <div class="lang-name">Français</div>
        </a>
    </li>

</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you may have to write safari specified css

Comment: The reference code doesn't have safari specific code and I didn't change much.